# Objective-C linking two Tableviews

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tableview

What I want is when you click on any cell in the table you go to another table view. I also need for each different cell you click on the view you get taken to has different strings. However I don't know

1) how to link a table cell to another tableview in the ViewController when you press it
2) how do you change the detail Tableview (including text and audio files) in View controller for each different cell you click on.

Comment: You should read about all the delegate methods of TableView https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview

Comment: Your question is inappropriate.. before get vote down correct your question..

Answer (score 1):

For detecting any row click in tableview use delegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

NSLog(@"index path cell row number =======%ld",(long)indexPath.row);//you can get the index number of that cell

NSLog(@"data of clicked cell====%@",[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);//here you can get the data of that cell

}
```